# Use state call to query from custom Runtime Api, Balance in frontend is not equal to Balance in Runtime

Tags: polkadot-js, custom-rpc, runtime-api, frontend

**Background**

Our front end use state call to query custom RuntimeApi of our solo chain.
We try to use state call to replace custom rpcs.

**Definition**

Balance is our chain is u128.

**RuntimeApi Definition**

```
impl parami_ad_runtime_api::AdRuntimeApi<Block, <BlakeTwo256 as sp_runtime::traits::Hash>::Output, NftId, DecentralizedId, Balance> for Runtime {
   fn cal_reward(ad_id: <BlakeTwo256 as sp_runtime::traits::Hash>::Output, nft_id: NftId, did: DecentralizedId, referrer: Option<DecentralizedId>) -> Result<Balance, DispatchError> {
        let visitor_in_runtime = Ad::cal_reward(ad_id, nft_id, did, referrer).unwrap();
        Ok(visitor_in_runtime)
    }
}
```

**Frontend implementation**

```
let resultOfFrontEnd = await api.call.adRuntimeApi.calReward("0x9cefa96e26ba9767a8c21fcc73d3b0912850e712b1a38945a1d2aaf8ccff5c58", 3, "0x5bc69eda41a4e6cf8b0a257b1c16b0d451eb95ee", null);
```

**Problem**
When i run the frontend, and debug run a local substrate node, I got the following confusing result;

1. `resultOfFronEnd` in the front end code is "256 Unit"
2. `result_in_runtime` in the runtime api implementation code is "1 Unit"

I also try other return value, the **regular pattern** is `resultOfFrontEnd = 256 * result_in_runtime`.

I really want to know why, or how can I reason about it.

Comment: Sounds like scale decoding fun. If there was a byte (eight bits) then that would shift things 8 times leading to * 256. Could one be using compressed encoding and the other not?

Comment: @Squirrel except compressed encoding, which one should i select to escape this issue ?

Comment: @Squirrel shall i create a pull request to fix this issue on compressed encoding?

Comment: I think it might well be a feature of the two different routes rather than a bug.